# Ссылки собираются по 2 раза в одном цикле. Что не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Собираю ссылки на сайте для дальнейшего разбора. Все как обычно, но почему-то как-то криво все собирается. В результате выполнения этого кода, из предполагаемых 60-ти ссылок (с 2-х страниц), собирает 90 ссылок. При этом ссылки с 1-й страницы повторяются по 2 раза, ссылки со 2-й страницы, по 1 разу  как  и должно быть. Вот сам код:

```
l1_links = []

for i in range(2, 4):
    url = 'https://krs-pobierz.pl/wojewodztwo/dolno%C5%9Bl%C4%85skie?q=&page={}'.format(i)
    time.sleep(3)
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    boxes = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-9')
    for w in boxes:
        woed_links = w.find('h4').find('a').get('href')
        l1_links.append(woed_links)

    with open('l1_links.txt', 'a') as f:
        for w in l1_links:
            f.write(f'{w}\n')
```

Comment: попробуйте записывать `[страница, ссылка]`, чтобы проверить: "скорее всего на второй странице дублируются ссылки".

Comment: Нет, не дублируются. Проверял уже

Comment: а у вас нет лишних отступов перед записью в файл? сейчас это происходит внутри цикла

Comment: Даже, меняя диапазон, к примеру на (3, 10), первая страница собирается 5 или 6 раза, вторая несколько раз и тд, только последняя в цикле 1 раз как и должно быть. Как будто обращается к первой странице столько раз, сколько страниц в цикле осталось и т.д ...

Comment: уберите из цикла запись в файл

Comment: Таки да, запихнул его в цикл случайно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два варианта решения проблемы:

1. Забываем очищать список `l1_links`, если запись в файл происходит
   в цикле. Для этого в начале цикла обнуляйте список
2. Просто вынесите запись в файл вне цикла